# How to loop audio in ffmpeg till concatenated video length

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

Here is my current code, but it cut shorts the concatenated video till audio length.

`ffmpeg -i 'vid1.mp4' -i 'vid2.mp4' -i 'vid3.mp4' -i 'audio1.mp3' -filter_complex [0:v][1:v][2:v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v] -map [v] -map 3:a -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -shortest -y output.mp4`

Comment: Could this help? https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23399/ffmpeg-building-video-with-audio-in-loop

Comment: @Renat Yes, i did try adding `-stream_loop -1` before the audio, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Works for me. Show your new command and the complete log.

Comment: @llogan cmd: `ffmpeg -i 'vid1.mp4' -i 'vid2.mp4' -i 'vid3.mp4' -stream_loop -1 -i 'aud.mp3' -filter_complex [0:v][1:v][2:v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v] -map [v] -map 3:a -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 50000 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -y output1.mp4`  , ffmpeg log - https://pastebin.com/LFXLyd62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering a bug that has already been fixed. FFmpeg 3.4.6 is old.

FFmpeg development is very active, so it is recommended to always use a recent version such as a build derived from the current git master branch.

Or at least when experiencing problems updating should be the first step.

You're on Ubuntu so you can get an already compiled ffmpeg from [johnvansickle.com](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (see [FAQ](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/) for install instructions) or follow step-by-step instrucitons at [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu Compile Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Once you update you can run this command:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -i vid3.mp4 -i audio1.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 3:a -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Is there a need to re-encode the video? how should the command be modified to copy instead?